# Comment POST request working but comments not appearing under post

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-settings

I'm relatively new to all this. I'm in the process of creating a social media page with django/python. The ability to create a post in a news feed (i.e. list of posts) and the ability to click on one post to see a more detailed view is working properly. When a user clicks on a single post to see it in more detail they also have the ability to add a comment.Here's the problem: the 'create a comment' input box is working fine, as is the 'post comment' button, but when you click the 'post comment' button my terminal does show that the comment is being posted, but the list of comments never appears.

What appears in my Powershell/Terminal when I click the 'post comment' button:

```
[DD/MONTH/2022 HH:MM:SS] "POST /social/post/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 3995
```

When the purple 'Post' button is clicked, the page refreshes, but the comment is never displayed below, nor does the comment box get cleared.

[image: screenshot of what appears on my website]

My `settings.py` installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'social',
    'landing',

    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',

    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
]
```

My `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm

class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = CommentForm()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-created_on')

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
        'comments': comments,
    } 
    return render(request, 'social/post_detail.html', context)

def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.author = request.user
        new_comment_post = post
        new_comment.save()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-created_on')

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
        'comments': comments,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'social/post_detail.html', context)
```

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

My `forms.py`:

```
    from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': '3',
            'placeholder': 'Share your ideas...'}
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['body']

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={'rows': '3',
            'placeholder': 'Share your opinion...'}
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
```

The actual html template that the comment function is on:

`post_detail.html`:

```
    {% extends 'landing/base.html' %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

    {% block content %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
            <h5>Add a Comment!</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form | crispy }}
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-light" style="background-color: #CC64C3; mt-3 mb-5">Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% for comment in comment %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-5 border-bottom">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12"> 
            <p>
                <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong> {{ comment.created_on }}
                {% if request.user == comment.author %}
                <a href="{% url 'comment-delete' post.pk comment.pk %}" style="color: #333;"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                {% endif %}
            </p>
            <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Typo: Instead of `new_comment_post = post` you should be writing `new_comment.post = post`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for picking that up! Unfortunately that hasn't fixed it, the page refreshes when the 'Post' button is clicked but the comment input box doesn't empty, nor does the comment appear belowhand.

Comment: Well the comment box doesn't empty out because you are displaying the same form to the user again, best practice when a form is submitted successfully is to redirect the user (either to the same page or elsewhere) you can do that at the end of the if block (`if form.is_valid():`). The other part of no comments being rendered is another typo `{% for comment in comment %}` should be `{% for comment in comments %}` (Notice the s)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Aha! I had tried that beforehand but because there was still the error with `new_comment_post = post` it didn't do anything. You are just a star thank you :)